# Identifying if code between code tags is JavaScript or HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to match block of code to check if is html or javascript code, i tried doing this but am having problem while when have this html element `"<div></div>"` or php `<? echo '';>` inside javascript code it will match it as html element.

Please can someone help me with best way to archive this?

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    function AssignLang(theLanguage){
    var regex = /(&lt;([^&gt;]+)&gt;|<([^>]+)>)/ig;
     //var regex = "<(\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*'|[^'\">])*>";
        if(theLanguage.match(regex)){
            var lang = 'markup';
        }else{
            var lang = 'javascript';
        }
        return lang;
    }

        $('pre code').each(function () {
       var the = $(this).html();
       /*I tried here to match from 0 to 50 but is not going to help because if the javascript tag begin with <script> still show as html
        var theLanguage = the.replace(/\s/g, '').substring(0,50);
       */
       var theLanguage = the.replace(/\s/g, '');
              var langType = AssignLang(theLanguage);
                $(this).addClass("fullcoded language-"+langType);
        alert(theLanguage+"-"+langType);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here am matching code inside pre and code element

```
        <pre><code>
          function check() {
    var delvar = "<? $_POST["del"]; ?>";
    var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete the article?")
    if (answer) {
        window.location = "adm-site.php?del=" + delvar + "&delete=true";
    }
}
        </code></pre>


 <pre><code>
<select name="del">
<option value="none" SELECTED></option>all articles echo'ed here by php
</select>  
</code></pre>
```

Here is a link to https://jsfiddle.net/ppu9qw3n/

Comment: Please i really do need help, i have been doing this for more thank 4 hours now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @Mr.George please i have search for solution but couldn't i really need help on this

Comment: Search SO for "Php html parser". You will definitely get an answer.

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi this i need for client side can't work with php i need it to automatically assign language type in prism highlight

Comment: I am on smartphone so unable to give you full solution. Take this for matching html code (\<[^;]+\>).*

Comment: It is based on the assumption that html code will not contain semi colon. You can develop the Regex on similar lines.

Comment: @StuartBrian Check my answer. It's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the regex I'm using `/\w+\s\w+\(\)/i`
\w+ matches 1 or more  a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and _ 
\s matches 1 space
\( and \) matches ()

Basically I'm searching for a pattern consisting of `function functionName()` in the code between code tags. If a match is found then it's JavasScript code or else it's HTML code.

This is how you can implement the JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var regex = /\w+\s\w+\(\)/i;
    $('pre code').each(function () {
        var v = $(this).html();
        if(regex.test(v)){
            alert(v+'-'+'THIS IS JAVASCRIPT CODE')
        }
        else{
            alert(v+'-'+'THIS IS HTML CODE')
        }
    });
});
```

Check it here on jsfiddle. It's working.
https://jsfiddle.net/swzaf5r1/

Comment: I did for you because you had tried so hard :). I refreshed some of javascript that I learnt doing this :)